# How can I make the calc++ example of bison-doc work?

Tags: c++, bison

I install some bison examples, by

```
$ sudo apt  install bison-doc

$ ls  /usr/share/doc/bison-doc/examples/calc++/
calc++.cc  calc++-driver.cc  calc++-driver.hh  calc++-parser.yy  calc++-scanner.ll
```

I then build it by creating a Makefile

```
$ cp -r /usr/share/doc/bison-doc/examples/calc++/ /tmp
$ cd /tmp/calc++/

$ cat Makefile
calc++: calc++-parser.yy calc++-scanner.ll calc++-driver.hh calc++-driver.cc calc++.cc
    bison calc++-parser.yy -o calc++-parser.cc
    flex calc++-scanner.ll
    g++ -o calc++ *.cc *.c -lm 
clean:
    rm calc++ *.o position.hh stack.hh location.hh calc++-parser.tab.hh calc++-parser.tab.cc calc++-parser.cc calc++-parser.hh lex.yy.c

$ make
bison calc++-parser.yy -o calc++-parser.cc
flex calc++-scanner.ll
g++ -o calc++ *.cc *.c -lm
```

But when I try to run the executable, it returns immediately instead of waiting for stdin input:

```
$ ./calc++
$
```

What did I do wrong? How can I make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From reading [`calc++.cc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Calc_002b_002b-Top-Level.html), it operates on files passed on the command-line. You can pass `/dev/stdin` as a filename to read stdin.

Also note that the quality of C++ support in bison has changed significantly in the last few versions, use bison 3.3 if possible.

Comment: Thanks. What does the option parsing in main() imply about? I can't tell the format of input from main().

Comment: `-s` and `-p` are just to debug the 2 phases, see the previous pages in the documentation. These can occur at any time and will affect only subsequently-named files.

Comment: That looks to me like a bug in the example. `driver::scan_begin` understands both an empty `file` or the string `"-"` as meaning `stdin`, but the top-level doesn't call the parser if there are no non-option command-line arguments. (`if (file.empty () || file == "-") yyin = stdin;`) (from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Calc_002b_002b-Scanner.html)).